# If `out` have one dimension more than `target`, the shape of `preds` should be (N, C, ...), and the shape of `target` should be (N, ...)

Tags: pytorch

I have a model with `7` outputs and I am trying to use [`torchmetrics.Accuracy`](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html).

My output shape has a shape of `(16, 7, 36)`, while my  target has a shape of `(16, 7)`. I am using `16` images per batch.

The error message I encounter is:

```
 If `out` have one dimension more than `target`, the shape of `out` should be (N, C, ...), and the shape of `target` should be (N, ...).
```

Comment: What kind of task is it? 7 outputs usually means 7 classes and should output shape [16, 7], while your target should be of shape [16, ] (with integer [0-6] representing classes). What is this 36 in your output shape?

Comment: Its a multioutput classfication, I have 7 outputs with 36 classes in each one @SzymonMaszke

Comment: According to docs you should have classes dimension as the second one, could you try using output.permute(0, 2, 1) and passing that to Accuracy?